# Laravel Spark install

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-spark

The problem I'm having is with the install
 **'Finally add that location to your system's PATH so that the spark executable can be run from anywhere on your system.'**

the spark command from terminal still isn't working and seems I'm stuck adding the Path variable correctly.

I've followed these steps and can see the following Paths inside of my .bashrc file :

in your ~/.bashrc add these lines:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/share/nginx/spark-installer"
```

Then reloaded:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Despite doing this, it's still not working.

I'm on a mac os x. Any help would be greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/usr/local/bin/../../autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /usr/local/bin/spark on line 7

Comment: Solved what I needed, I realized I had that incorrect.

for me what worked was,

    cd ~/

    composer global require laravel/spark-installer

    export PATH="$HOME/Spark-Installer:$PATH"